# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.How do i edit the image?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, accessibility

i know there's a lot of these type of questions. i wanted to post so that i can share my specific prob because im getting frustrated.

im running a thread which query path from db and put it in the image element.problem is, i created the image in xaml so when i run this thread it throws the cannot access this object error which it cant access the image element.

then how do i set it without using xaml??here's my code snippet:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{


    Thread Frame1;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        intializeDb();
        #region start frame 1 thread
        Frame1 = new Thread(frame1);
        Frame1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        Frame1.IsBackground = true;
        Frame1.Start();
        #endregion 

    }

public void frame1()
    {
        string k;

        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM imageframe1";
        sqlConn.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
            logo.BeginInit();
            k = (string)(Reader.GetValue(1));
            logo.UriSource = new Uri(k);
            logo.EndInit();
            image1.Source = logo; //THROWS THE ERROR HERE.IT CANT ACCESS image1
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        sqlConn.Close();
        Reader.Close();

    }
```

how would i access `image1` then? if i create a new one within the thread,i will have to put as child of a panel,an then im gonna get an error which it cant access the panel.

any way around this?glad if someone can write an example based on my snippet.

**edited with still no success and producing the same error:**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public readonly SynchronizationContext mySynchronizationContext;

public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mySynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        Frame1 = new Thread(frame1);
        Frame1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        Frame1.IsBackground = true;
        Frame1.Start();
    }

public void frame1()
    {
        string k;

        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM imageframe1";
        sqlConn.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();



        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
            logo.BeginInit();
            k = (string)(Reader.GetValue(1));
            logo.UriSource = new Uri(k);
            logo.EndInit();
            SendOrPostCallback callback = _ =>
            {
                image1.Source = logo;
            };

            mySynchronizationContext.Send(callback, null);

            //image1.Source = logo;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        sqlConn.Close();
        Reader.Close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Jon Skeet said, you can use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to assign the image, but it's not enough, because the `BitmapImage` has been created on another thread. To be able to use it on the UI thread, you need to `Freeze` it before:

```
logo.Freeze();
Action action = delegate { image1.Source = logo; };
image1.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

Comment: You really saved my life! thnx a bunch! i've never come across Freeze before.im going to read it to understanda whats going on.thnx again.

Comment: Wow!!!! Really, Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{...}); not enough! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) associated with the control you want to update:

```
Action action = delegate { image1.Source = logo; };
image1.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

Note that using `Thread.Sleep` like this to perform animation is unlikely to give a very good experience... especially as the display thread then has to fetch the URI in order to display the image. It's not going to be very smooth.

Comment: just like that??where should i put it?please help..yep,i know it wont be smooth.thnx.but im going one by one here.later i'll want to learn to do the proper animation.

Comment: now i get this error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: @Psychocryo: The exception should be specified as a nested exception - have a look at the complete stack trace and it should explain what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is because you didnt marshal the call to the UI thread. you can do something line this:

save the context in the constructor,

```
// this is a class member variable 
public readonly SynchronizationContext mySynchronizationContext;

// in ctor
MySynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

// in your method , to set the image:    
SendOrPostCallback callback = _=>
{
  image1.Source = logo;
};

mySynchronizationContext.Send(callback,null);
```

by the way, its a good practice to use using statements with the `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader`. as in:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("conn string here"))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // db access code
    }
}
```

Comment: i see a more elegant solution here from Jon. man you are fast

Comment: i didnt get it working.it returns the same error as the original.@Menahem

Comment: where did you save the SynchronizationContext? it should be in `public Window1()` before the thread is started

Comment: yep i put it in public window1() but doesnt make any difference.

Comment: can you post the updated code . maybe i can spot the problem?

Comment: public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mySynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

Comment: @Psychocryo, the code you posted looks good, but i see the problem was not related. i'll keep the answer around  since its not entirely out of context.